# How to get updated blob list?

Tags: javascript, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

How to fetch updated list of blobs from azure, When a new file has been added to blob storage??

This is the code which fetches the blobs from azure-storage

```
blobService.listContainersSegmented(null, function (error, results) {
    if (error) {
        // List container error
    } else {
        for (var i = 0, container; container = results.entries[i]; i++) {
            // Deal with container object
        }
    }
});
```

Is there any Listener or Stream to get updated list when a new blob is added?

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you mean a blob trigger function?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=javascript

Answer (score 0):

Azure Storage originally didn't have any facility to see updates based on any events: you'd have to list and analyze every blob to determine this on your own (as described in [this question and set of answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36266792/getting-the-latest-file-modified-from-azure-blob)).

Now, Azure Event Grid provides this ability, and you may choose events for:

- blobs created or replaced
- blobs deleted

If you use hierarchical directories (e.g. ADLS on top of Azure Storage), you get even more options (such as renames, as well as directory-level events).

Event Grid events are consumable via Azure Functions, Logic Apps, or an HTTP listener.

More details are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-event-overview).

Comment: To second what @DavidMakogon said, we use the the Blob events in Logic Apps all the time - it works great and is very easy to set up. One caveat: if you specify a container using the "Prefix filter", be sure to include a trailing '/' to specify a single container: "/blobServices/default/containers/{containername}/". Without it you may inadvertently specify multiple containers.